A javascript error in the main process tmp.node
Every time I boot up my system, I encounter the following error message:

"A javascript error in the main process" with reference to C:\Users\mpc\AppData\Local\Temp\f06d063a-bde0-4c9f-ad00-8786969258ab.tmp.node.

Despite this error, my system seems to function normally, but the constant popup is becoming bothersome.
I attempted to resolve this issue by installing Malwarebytes, but unfortunately, it did not provide any solution.
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

It's unknown what's the cause. This node module that is presumably used by some Electron-based app. A lot of apps are made this way, it could be a malware or not. You can easily distinguish them on a disk because they occupy 200+ mbs, in case of malware it makes it harder to hide them. This is more the question for superuser.com but it still requires more specifics, otherwise you have to audit all your autoruns, etc

if it's on startup, at the very least check your lists of startup apps (depending on the version of windows you're in there are different locations for this, there are plenty of superuser.com posts on where to find those)
